# Why I can see cookies in Firebug but getCookies returns NULL?

Tags: servlets, cookies, firebug, servlet-filters

In one of our web applications I used Firebug to view the cookies it sets and was able to see two cookies (both listed with domain `localhost`, since the server is running on my machine).

When I submitted the page and on the server side (in Filter) I used `request.getCookies()` to retrieve them, the call returned `NULL`. What could be the reason?

We do not have any `addCookie()` code in the server code. I checked with the UI team, but they are not sure of having any code related to cookies.

If so, why are cookies listed in Firebug's *Cookies* panel? Why am I not getting those cookies on the server side?

**Note:** The cookie name is 'sessionCheck'. This is exactly the same value, which I intend to use for some purpose. I don't think this is accidentally getting listed in Firebug as a cookie.

Comment: You may need to explicitly set the path of the cookie, for example, if it is '/' then be explicit about that. Otherwise the server and client may set different path values that look similar. I'm sure I've seen cookies not read because the default path setting wasn't recognised.

Comment: i manually tried creating a in Firebug console before posting the page. This way, i ensured this manually created cookie has the correct domain [localhost:8080] and path [/dashboard] of my current page which is going to be posted. Still the server is getting NULL for getCookie()

Comment: A screenshot of Firebug's *Cookies* panel could help. Note that you need to check the option *Filter Cookies By Current Path* within the *Filter* menu to only show cookies that apply to the current URL path.